# htaccess variables not working with username

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

So I have a rewrite rule for user names as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z0-9a-z\~\^\(\)_\-\+\{\}\[\]\|:\<\>\.]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This works fine, and I can echo $_GET['user'] no problem.  The issue happens when I add another variable to the rewrite rule as follows -

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z0-9a-z\~\^\(\)_\-\+\{\}\[\]\|:\<\>\.]+)$/?extra$ index.php?user=$1&system_page=extra [L]
```

I was hoping to be able to go to http//localhost/test/username/extra and echo $_GET['system_page'] with the result of "extra", but I receive a 404 error instead.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  For any of you who run into the same problem, the solution is to remove the "$" after the username definition.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z0-9a-z\~\^\(\)_\-\+\{\}\[\]\|:\<\>\.]+)$/?extra$
```

should instead be -

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z0-9a-z\~\^\(\)_\-\+\{\}\[\]\|:\<\>\.]+)/?extra$
```